# BigQuery - How to do a Left Join by the closest date?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, analytics

Using BigQuery, How to do a Left Join  to Customer Book Table  by the closest date  on the  Customer Score Table?
I want to the choose the closest  Open_Date_Score  that is prior to the Open_Date_Book?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqWlM.png)

Wanted Results

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRxdM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, partition your data on ID and rank the date for closeness and then filter the date to show only the closest date. This code should point you in the right direction Customer Book Table=cbt
Customer Score Table=cst

```
SELECT
cbt.ID,
cbt.Open_Date_Book,
cst.Score,
cst.Open_Date_Score
FROM
CustomerBookTable cbt
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
ID,
Open_Date_Score,
Score,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 
ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(Open_Date_Score, 
Open_Date_Book, SECOND))) AS rn
FROM
CustomerScoreTable
JOIN
CustomerBookTable
ON
CustomerScoreTable.ID = CustomerBookTable.ID
WHERE
Open_Date_Score <= Open_Date_Book
) cst ON cbt.ID = cst.ID
WHERE
cst.rn = 1
```